# jsf primefaces reset the wizard and set all values to null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wizard

I am using prime faces wizard with three tabs, each tab is dependent on the previous one, when I reach the last one I have a button that takes the user back to the first tab, my code works but the problem is I have a selectOneMenu that has a values from a dataTable and I would like to set to null but I keep getting what I have chosen before. I have tried the following code:

```
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("frmExamBank");
    setCourseExamBank(null);
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("frmExamBank");
```

But nothing worked for me, I keep getting the same values and when I choose a different dataTable item it does not change in the next tab but it gets my old value.

Can someone advice.

Comment: can you share the wizard code?